# Set channel permissions to only allow the ticket opener and admin to view the channel - Discord ticket system

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, discord, discord.js

I'm having an issue with my ticket discord system where the lock react emoji doesn't actually lock the text chat. The overall slash command executes and my second react emoji, which is an X used to delete the text chat works, but the locking system does not.

The structure is written that any member within the discord will use the /ticket command in "open a ticket" chat and the bot will then create a ticket in a new text channel and name it ticket-userid, and once an admin comes to help the ticket he will then react to the "lock" emoji and lock to channel where only him and the member can see it, no one else. But it's not executing like this, only everything else except this. Does anyone have any idea?

ticket.js

```js
name: 'ticket',
    aliases: [],
    permissions: [],
    description: 'open a ticket!',
    async execute(interaction) {
        // message.guild is now interaction.guild
        const channel = await interaction.guild.channels.create(
            // message.author.tag is now interaction.user.tag
            `ticket: ${interaction.user.tag}`,
        );

        channel.setParent('932177870661509141');

        // message.guild is now interaction.guild
        channel.permissionOverwrites.edit(interaction.guild.id, {
            SEND_MESSAGES: false,
            VIEW_CHANNEL: false,
        });

        // message.author is now interaction.member
        channel.permissionOverwrites.edit(interaction.member, {
            SEND_MESSAGES: true,
            VIEW_CHANNEL: true,
        });

        // we're sending a reply with interaction.reply
        // and use fetchReply so we can delete it after 7 seconds
        const reply = await interaction.reply({
            content: `We will be right with you! ${channel}`,
            fetchReply: true,
        });

        setTimeout(() => {
            reply.delete();
        }, 7000);

        const reactionMessage = await channel.send(
            'Thank you for contacting support!',
        );

        try {
            await reactionMessage.react('');
            await reactionMessage.react('');
        } catch (err) {
            channel.send('Error sending emojis!');
            throw err;
        }
        // you should also check if the user reacted is a bot
        const filter = (reaction, user) =>
            !user.bot &&
            interaction.guild.members.cache
                .get(user.id)
                .permissions.has('ADMINISTRATOR');

        const collector = reactionMessage.createReactionCollector({
            dispose: true,
            filter,
        });

        collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
            switch (reaction.emoji.name) {
                case '':
                    channel.permissionOverwrites.edit(interaction.member, {
                        SEND_MESSAGES: false,
                    });
                    break;
                case '':
                    channel.send('Deleting this channel in 5 seconds!');
                    setTimeout(() => channel.delete(), 5000);
                    break;
            }
        });
    },
};
```

index.js

```js
    const fs = require('fs');
    const { Client, Collection, Intents, DiscordAPIError } = require('discord.js');
    const { token } = require('./config.json');
    const prefex = '!';
    
    const client = new Client({
        intents: [
            Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
            Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
            Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
        ],
    });
    
    client.commands = new Collection();
    client.events = new Collection();
    const commandFiles = fs
        .readdirSync('./commands')
        .filter((file) => file.endsWith('.js'));
    
    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
        client.commands.set(command.name, command);
    }
    
    client.once('ready', () => {
        console.log("You are now connected to Boombap Tickets!");
    });
    
    client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
        if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;
    
        const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);
    
        if (!command) return;
    
        try {
            await command.execute(interaction);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            return interaction.reply({
                content: 'There was an error while executing this command!',
                ephemeral: true,
            });
        }
    });

client.login(token);
```

Comment: According to your code, when you open a ticket, only admin and the opener can see the channel and send a message. When you click the lock emoji then the one who reacted can't send message. And you want that when an admin clicks the lock button, only admins can send messages. Right?

Comment: I want it where the lock button would lock the channel to where only me and the person who created the ticket can see the chat, currently with the code I have, after I create the ticket on an alt discord account, everyone can see the text chat even after reacting the the lock emoji

Comment: then what is the difference between unlocked and locked? Only admin and opener can see the chat. Or sending message disabled to opener when locked?

Comment: so basically, the category is set to where everyone in the server can see it and there is also a text chat within the category called "create-a-ticket" where everyone also can see and this text chat is where the people in the server will input the slash command "/ticket" and create a ticket, making a new text chat within this category called "ticket-user" and once this chat is made, people in the server should not be able to see it once the admin interacts with the "lock" emoji and in a certain sense locking the channel from everyone else except the user who made the ticket and the admin

Comment: So Unlocked: everyone can see, opener can see and chat. Locked: everyone can't see, opener can see and chat. Mods can always see and chat. Right?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: I'll write an answer. Last question: can everyone chat when unlocked? And does the bot do something when reacted?

Comment: wdym? like everyone can chat within the ticket created or under text chats under the ticket category?

Answer (score 0):

```js
channel.permissionOverwrites.edit(interaction.member, {
  SEND_MESSAGES: false
});
```

In this code, the bot sets permission overwrite for reacted person(actually a mod) to restrict sending messages.

But since admins have full privileges, it has no effect.

Instead, you need to restrict `@everyone` of viewing the channel.

Also you can put all the role id to restrict access in an array and iterate over it to edit overwrites and restrict their access.

So the code would be:

```js
channel.permissionOverwrites.edit(interaction.guild.id, {
  VIEW_CHANNEL: false
});
['headchef-role-id', 'cook-role-id'].forEach(roleId => {
  channel.permissionOverwrites.edit(roleId, {
  VIEW_CHANNEL: false
  });
});
```

Also when opening, your code restricts `@everyone` to view and send. But since you want `@everyone` to view the channel, set overwrites code would be:

```js
channel.permissionOverwrites.edit(interaction.member, {
  VIEW_CHANNEL: true,
  SEND_MESSAGES: false
});
channel.permissionOverwrites.edit(interaction.guild.id, {
  VIEW_CHANNEL: true,
  SEND_MESSAGES: false
});
```

Also please note that when creating a channel, its name isn't `ticket: user#1234`. It would be `ticket-user1234`.

Comment: so its almost right, so currently i have 4 roles, executive chef which is administrative permissions and only I have it, and 3 other roles which is head chefs (every permissions except administrator, cooks and members ( which have the same permissions) but cooks is separated where it ranks higher. And the current code you sent me works to where it blocks out roles, but only people with "member" role and not cooks and head chefs which can also still see the text channel after "lock" emoji is interacted with

Comment: @senpai so my code works well except that when locked cooks and head chefs can see channel but they shouldn't?

Comment: yes thats correct

Comment: @senpai i edited the answer.

Comment: where it says headchef-role-id and cook-role-id do i just replace that with the role id

Comment: @senpai exactly.

Comment: thank you so much, it works with no hiccups!

Comment: @senpai Glad to have been of help! Feel free to [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) if you feel it was useful to you. :-)